# Update schema just from yml in Symfony2 with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to add an item like this **just** to the src/Acme/AdminBundle/Entity/Artist.orm.yml:

```
email:
  type: string
  column: email_address
  length: 150
```

but I'm forced to do the same in the file Acme/AdminBundle/Entity/Artist

```
/**
 * @var string $email
 */
private $email;
```

If I don't do it, when I update the schema it shows an error:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
  An error occurred in Acme\AdminBundle\Entity\Artist

[ReflectionException]
  Property email does not exist

I generated the Bundle with the yml option at the beginning.

Comment: What you are quoting as annotation is **not** the doctrine2 annotation but the normal PHP annotations which are used by PHPDoc or your IDE to determine the type of your field. I don't think this is needed for doctrine2 to operate. Reading the doctrine2 docs (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html) I don't see that there are annotations needed. What happens if you remove the annotations?

Comment: I'm forced to put private $email in the Entity, if not, It doesn't let me update le schema:  [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]              
  An error occurred in Acme\AdminBundle\Entity\Artist  

  [ReflectionException]            
  Property email does not exist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, generate the entity class file

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities [Your]/[Bundle]/Entity/Artist --path="src/" --no-backup
```

The "--path" param must be given if there is a new entity to be generated.

Then, update your schema:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I managed to solve it.

doctrine:generate:entity generates the .php entity file at "Entity" but it also generates a orm file at "Resources/config/doctrine" which can create conflicts if you modify the .php entity file.

I just deleted the orm files and it works as expected.